# Custom install onto UEFI-only machine

Tags: boot, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 via USB onto a Dell 7060, which only allows EFI boot when booting from HD. I am passing -isohybrid-mbr to xorriso **CLARIFYING EDIT: and installing from legacy-mode**, and things seem to install ok, but after removing the USB and rebooting, I get the error, "No bootable devices found." My current xorriso arguments are:

## Source: http://askubuntu.com/questions/625286/how-to-create-uefi-bootable-iso

```
remaster_iso() {

    cd "${BASEDIR}/extract-cd"

    sudo xorriso -as mkisofs \
                 -iso-level 3 \
                 -isohybrid-mbr /usr/lib/syslinux/isohdpfx.bin \
                 -c isolinux/boot.cat \
                 -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
                 -no-emul-boot \
                 -boot-load-size 4 \
                 -boot-info-table \
                 -eltorito-alt-boot \
                 -e boot/grub/efi.img \
                 -no-emul-boot \
                 -isohybrid-gpt-basdat \
                 -D -r -J -l -V "${ISO_LABEL}" \
                 -o ../staging/"$ISO_COMMON_NAME-$ISO_VERSION-$ISO_BUILDNUM.iso" .
```

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

EDIT: One thing which helped was figuring out which cfg file *was* getting called. In legacy boot mode, we were using an edited version of txt.cfg. But in EFI mode, the menu appearing was boot/grub/grub.cfg, which seems to be called by the boot/grub/efi.img we are passing in the command above. Editing the boot.cfg file to include an option which uses our preseed allows the installation to proceed mostly as planned.

Comment: Is this a single installation to the Dell 7060? In that case, you can install from a USB drive made from the standard Ubuntu iso file. It can boot in UEFI mode, and you can install Ubuntu. After the installation you can add any program packages and tweaks. You can even make an [OEM system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview), which can be ported (as an installed system) to other computers of the same kind, but also to different computers. But it is not as portable as an Ubuntu live drive (made from an iso file).

Comment: Single boot. OEM install looks interesting, but our current process is to install everything at once, and it would be preferable to continue to do so.

Comment: okay so since you figured it out, why not write an answer, so everyone can join your newly achieved knowledge

Comment: If no one writes up something nice about how the .img and .cfg files are interconnected in the next day or so, I will write up my hacky guesswork.

Comment: @ctd, We are looking forward to your solution :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xorriso turned out to be a bad guess. My guess which seemed to work was to install using EFI. Installing in legacy boot mode for the install USB resulted in an HD without an EFIboot partition. The problem was, I could only see my custom install menu when booting from legacy mode.

So, I needed a way to do an EFI install using my [preseed file](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed). I looked through the grub files on the USB installer and compared them to the GRUB menu I was seeing in EFI boot, and found that the boot/grub/grub.cfg file matched. So I added the following entry:

```
menuentry "Install My Custom Thingy" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/my_custom.seed quiet --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
```

This got everything working.